# Establishing and creating a many to many relationship with Pandas and one CSV sheet

Tags: python, pandas, many-to-many

I have a csv that I import with two ID's, ID1 and ID2. There is a many-to-many relationship on between the two ID's. Ultimately I would like to create two things, one summaries and two a listing of all possible ID1's and ID2's that are associated with a single group.

Here is one sample of what I mean:

```
    ID1         ID2
0   46667523    9122532
1   55189732    9122532
2   71453880    9122532
3   77817617    9122532
4   77817617    79834910
5   79871820    9122532
6   79871820    79834910
7   98158277    9122532
8   98158277    458182615
9   134303192   9122532
10  187502299   458182615
```

All of these ID's in this small sample represent one single grouping. I would like to add a new column ID_New where for this example they would all be equal.

```
    ID1         ID2       ID_New
0   46667523    9122532   1
1   55189732    9122532   1
2   71453880    9122532   1
3   77817617    9122532   1
4   77817617    79834910  1
5   79871820    9122532   1
6   79871820    79834910  1
7   98158277    9122532   1
8   98158277    458182615 1
9   134303192   9122532   1
10  187502299   458182615 1
```

The final dataset isn't huge maybe 100,000 rows, how do I create and set up a many-to-many relationship with pandas?

Comment: If you need additional data/info let me know and I can send you the csv I am working with.

Comment: How do you decide the grouping?

Comment: `test = df[['ID2', 'ID1']]`
`test1 = test.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID1', 'ID2'])`

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on what you're trying to do?
How is dropping duplicates grouping anything?